# How to get extension of a file from textbox using jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<!-- Modal File Add -->
<div class="modal fade" id="file" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Add File</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="" class="form-horizontal" data-validate="parsley" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="validate-form-service" method="post" autocomplete="off">
          <?php echo "Selected Id Is = " . $data["worker_id"]; ?>
          <input type="hidden" name="worker_id">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Select File</label>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
              <input type="file" name="worker_file" id="worker_file" class="form-control"><small>Maximum File Size 5MB Only</small>
            </div>
          </div>


          <input type="submit" data-file="worker_file" value="Add File" class="btn-primary btn" onclick="javascript:$('#validate-form-service').parsley('validate');">
        </form>

      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->


<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="file"]').change(function(e) {
      var fileName = e.target.files[0].name;
      //alert(ext);
      alert('The file "' + fileName + '" has been selected.');
    });
  });
  //     $('#worker_file').on('change', function() {
  //     alert( this.value );

  // });
</script>
```

Comment: Please clarify what problem is

Comment: filename is showing in alert but i want it's extension also be shown separately in the alert

Comment: try: `alert('ext "' + fileName.split('.').pop() + '" has been selected.');`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
var fileName = e.target.files[0].name.split('.');
var ex = fileName.pop();
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="file"]').change(function(e) {
    var fileName = e.target.files[0].name.split('.');
    var ex = fileName.pop();
    alert('The file "' + fileName + '" has been selected., with the extension ' + ex);
  });
});
//     $('#worker_file').on('change', function() {
//     alert( this.value );

// });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade" id="file" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Add File</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="" class="form-horizontal" data-validate="parsley" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="validate-form-service" method="post" autocomplete="off">
          <?php echo "Selected Id Is = " . $data["worker_id"]; ?>
          <input type="hidden" name="worker_id">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Select File</label>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
              <input type="file" name="worker_file" id="worker_file" class="form-control"><small>Maximum File Size 5MB Only</small>
            </div>
          </div>


          <input type="submit" data-file="worker_file" value="Add File" class="btn-primary btn" onclick="javascript:$('#validate-form-service').parsley('validate');">
        </form>

      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```